# How to transfer data from page to another in node js

Tags: node.js, authentication

Hello there i am learning `node.js` and got stuck in a scenario.The flow is that in website user register himself and after successfully registering i will be sending him to route named `create_profile` which in is post request and also i want to send `userId` to `create_profile` route.In case if user close the website then if he agains open it and login then if profile is incomplete then i will be taking his `userId` and send to `create_profile` route.And after that to home page.What i was thinking to store session for user authentication in create profile page and login.This is because if login there can be tow cases : If user has successfully completed his profile then take him to home and store a global session there and second case it to take him to create profile as its incomplete then after successfully creating take him to home store global session for user authentication.But my confusion is to how to pass userId from login to create profile which is post request.Do i need to make temp session ? Please solve my issue i am confused how to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a "profile_completed" column in DB and set it as "false" (default), update it to "true" if user has completed the profile. While user login check if his profile is updated, if yes send him to home else ask him to update.
2. You can pass user I'd to `create_profile` via request or get it from session storage you saved earlier